# MySQL Replace quotes with brackets

Tags: mysql

Hey everyone, I've got a problem and Google hasn't yielded the help I need so I'm turning to the experts ;)

I've got a MySQL database and one field is used for user input. Some users feel the need to quote their entry like so: "cheese press" and I need to change all entries in that column that have "quotes" to brackets like so: (cheese press)

I've tried these:

```
UPDATE `inputColumn` SET `userInput` = REPLACE(`userInput`, '"', '(');
```

The results were obvious the second I hit enter: (cheese press(
I did this on a test field, no worries.

Then I tried:

```
UPDATE `inputColumn` SET `userInput` = REPLACE(`userInput`, '"%', '(');
```

That didn't do anything at all and neither did

```
UPDATE `inputColumn` SET `userInput` = REPLACE(`userInput`, '"%"', '(%)');
```

I really don't want to go through and update 3000 records manually :) any ideas?

Comment: This should be done at the application level before it gets into the database. This is fine for a one off deal, but use the app to filter these things out in the future.

Comment: Also, those are parens/parentheses, brackets are typically []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this.

```
UPDATE `inputColumn`
SET    `userInput` = CONCAT('(', SUBSTR(`userInput`, 2, LENGTH(`userInput`)-2), ')')
WHERE  `userInput` LIKE '"%"';
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit of a cludge but if you can trust that there is a space before the first quote and a space after the second then try

```
UPDATE `inputColumn` SET `userInput` = REPLACE(`userInput`, ' "', ' (');
```

and

```
UPDATE `inputColumn` SET `userInput` = REPLACE(`userInput`, '" ', ')');
```

Note the spaces and different brackets.

Comment: Hmm that gives me some ideas. From my brief look, there aren't any spaces before the first quote, but occasionally there is a space after the second. I could run that change on the second bracket first, then do a blanket update on quotes to change them all to (. I'd have some cleanup to do, but it would certainly cut down on the total amount of changes I'd have to make manually...I'll give this a try and update this thread. Thanks!